Fixing ModuleError after cloning repository
The code below is an example from a repository called "pyrk" it stands for Python Reactor Kinetics. I downloaded the repository and followed the setup instructions but I keep getting a ModuleError and I don't know how to fix it.
from pyrk.utilities.ur import units
from pyrk import th_component as th
import math
from pyrk.materials.flibe import Flibe
from pyrk.materials.graphite import Graphite
from pyrk.materials.kernel import Kernel
from pyrk.timer import Timer

#############################################
#
# User Workspace
#
#############################################

# Thermal hydraulic params
# Temperature feedbacks of reactivity
alpha_f = -3.8 * units.pcm / units.kelvin
alpha_c = -1.8 * units.pcm / units.kelvin
alpha_m = -0.7 * units.pcm / units.kelvin
alpha_r = 1.8 * units.pcm / units.kelvin
# below from steady state analysis
t_fuel = 955.58086 * units.kelvin
t_cool = 936.57636 * units.kelvin
t_refl = 923.18521 * units.kelvin
t_mod = 937.39862 * units.kelvin
t_graph_peb = 936.40806 * units.kelvin
t_core = 970.54064 * units.kelvin

# the data below comes from design doc rev c

# self._vol_flow_rate = 976.0*0.3 # kg/s TODO 0.3 is nat circ guess
vel_cool = 2. * units.meter / units.second  # m/s
t_inlet = units.Quantity(600.0, units.degC)  # degrees C
# [m] ... matrix(4mm) + coating(1mm)
thickness_fuel_matrix = 0.005 * units.meter
kappa = 0.00  # TODO if you fix omegas, kappa ~ 0.06
core_height = 3.5 * units.meter  # [m] (TODO currently approximate)
core_inner_radius = 0.35 * units.meter  # m
core_outer_radius = 1.25 * units.meter  #

# Initial time
t0 = 0.00 * units.seconds

# Timestep
dt = 0.005 * units.seconds

# Final Time
tf = 5.0 * units.seconds


def area_sphere(r):
    assert(r >= 0 * units.meter)
    return (4.0) * math.pi * pow(r.to('meter'), 2)


def vol_sphere(r):
    assert(r >= 0 * units.meter)
    return (4. / 3.) * math.pi * pow(r.to('meter'), 3)


# volumes
n_pebbles = 470000
n_graph_peb = 218000
n_particles_per_pebble = 4730
r_pebble = 0.015 * units.meter  # [m] diam = 3cm
r_core = 0.0125 * units.meter  # [m] diam = 2.5cm
r_particle = 200 * units.micrometer

# vol of 4730 kernels per pebble, each 400 micrometer diameter
vol_fuel = n_pebbles * n_particles_per_pebble * vol_sphere(r_particle)
vol_core = (n_pebbles) * (vol_sphere(r_core))
vol_mod = (n_pebbles) * (vol_sphere(r_pebble) - vol_sphere(r_core)) - vol_fuel
vol_graph_peb = (n_graph_peb) * (vol_sphere(r_pebble))

# from design report
vol_cool = 7.20 * units.meter**3
mass_inner_refl = 43310.0 * units.kg
mass_outer_refl = 5940.0 * units.kg
mass_refl = mass_inner_refl + mass_outer_refl
rho_refl = 1740.0 * units.kg / units.meter**3
vol_refl = mass_refl / rho_refl

a_core = area_sphere(r_core) * n_pebbles
a_mod = area_sphere(r_pebble) * n_pebbles
a_graph_peb = area_sphere(r_pebble) * n_graph_peb
a_fuel = area_sphere(r_particle) * n_pebbles * n_particles_per_pebble
a_refl = 2 * math.pi * core_outer_radius * core_height

# TODO implement h(T) model
h_mod = 4700 * units.watt / units.kelvin / units.meter**2
# TODO placeholder
h_refl = 600 * units.watt / units.kelvin / units.meter**2

# modified alphas for mod
vol_mod_tot = vol_mod + vol_graph_peb + vol_core
alpha_mod = alpha_m * vol_mod / vol_mod_tot
alpha_core = alpha_m * vol_core / vol_mod_tot
alpha_graph_peb = alpha_m * vol_graph_peb / vol_mod_tot

#############################################
#
# Required Input
#
#############################################

# Total power, Watts, thermal
power_tot = 236000000.0 * units.watt

# Timer instance, based on t0, tf, dt
ti = Timer(t0=t0, tf=tf, dt=dt)

# Number of precursor groups
n_pg = 6

# Number of decay heat groups
n_dg = 0

# Fissioning Isotope
fission_iso = "u235"

# Spectrum
spectrum = "thermal"

# Feedbacks, False to turn reactivity feedback off. True otherwise.
feedback = True

# External Reactivity
from reactivity_insertion import StepReactivityInsertion
rho_ext = StepReactivityInsertion(timer=ti, t_step=1.0 * units.seconds,
                                  rho_init=0.0 * units.delta_k,
                                  rho_final=0.005 * units.delta_k)

# maximum number of internal steps that the ode solver will take
nsteps = 1000


fuel = th.THComponent(name="fuel",
                      mat=Kernel(name="fuelkernel"),
                      vol=vol_fuel,
                      T0=t_fuel,
                      alpha_temp=alpha_f,
                      timer=ti,
                      heatgen=True,
                      power_tot=power_tot)

cool = th.THComponent(name="cool",
                      mat=Flibe(name="flibe"),
                      vol=vol_cool,
                      T0=t_cool,
                      alpha_temp=alpha_c,
                      timer=ti)

refl = th.THComponent(name="refl",
                      mat=Graphite(name="reflgraphite"),
                      vol=vol_refl,
                      T0=t_refl,
                      alpha_temp=alpha_r,
                      timer=ti)

mod = th.THComponent(name="mod",
                     mat=Graphite(name="pebgraphite"),
                     vol=vol_mod,
                     T0=t_mod,
                     alpha_temp=alpha_mod,
                     timer=ti)

core = th.THComponent(name="core",
                      mat=Graphite(name="pebgraphite"),
                      vol=vol_core,
                      T0=t_core,
                      alpha_temp=alpha_core,
                      timer=ti)

graph_peb = th.THComponent(name="graph_peb",
                           mat=Graphite(name="pebgraphite"),
                           vol=vol_mod,
                           T0=t_graph_peb,
                           alpha_temp=alpha_graph_peb,
                           timer=ti)

components = [fuel, cool, refl, mod, graph_peb, core]

# TODO: verify the conduction lengths and maybe calibrate for spherical components
# The fuel conducts to the moderator graphite
fuel.add_conduction('mod', area=a_fuel, L=4 * units.millimeter)

# The moderator graphite conducts to the core graphite
mod.add_conduction('core', area=a_core, L=25 * units.millimeter)
# The moderator graphite conducts to the fuel
mod.add_conduction('fuel', area=a_mod, L=25 * units.millimeter)
# The moderator graphite convects to the coolant
mod.add_convection('cool', h=h_mod, area=a_mod)

# The core graphite conducts to the moderator graphite
core.add_conduction('mod', area=a_core, L=25 * units.centimeter)

# The graphite pebbles convect to the coolant
graph_peb.add_convection('cool', h=h_mod, area=a_graph_peb)

# The coolant convects accross the graphite pebbles
cool.add_convection('graph_peb', h=h_mod, area=a_graph_peb)
# The coolant convects accross the graphite pebbles
cool.add_convection('mod', h=h_mod, area=a_mod)
# The coolant convects accross the reflector
cool.add_convection('refl', h=h_refl, area=a_refl)

# The reflector convects with the coolant
refl.add_convection('cool', h=h_refl, area=a_refl)


I tried creating modules called "main.py, pyrk.py, and utilities.py" which were the main ModuleErrors I was getting. These didn't work because the code is trying to call upon something within those files specifically but I'm not sure what it is.
